# Hibernate SessionFactory: how to configure JNDI in Tomcat?

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, jndi, sessionfactory

that's how the session factory should be gotten:

```
    protected SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        try {
            return (SessionFactory) new InitialContext()
                    .lookup("SessionFactory");
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
```

**Please provide a simple solution for Tomcat6 to be able to get SessionFactory
thru simple jndi lookup in Java code.
What should be written in what file on the side of Tomcat ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a link
http://community.jboss.org/wiki/UsingJNDI-boundSessionFactorywithTomcat41

But other answers are welcome as well.

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat documentation [says](https://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/TomcatHibernate):

> Tomcat provides a read-only `InitialContext`, while Hibernate requires
>   read-write in order to manage multiple session factories. Tomcat is
>   apparently following the specification for unmanaged containers. If
>   you want to bind the session factory to a JNDI object, you'll either
>   have to move to a managed server (Glassfish, JBoss, etc.), or search
>   on the Internet for some posted work-arounds.
>
> The recommendation from the Hibernate documentation is to just leave
>   out the `hibernate.session_factory_name` property when working with
>   Tomcat to not try binding to JNDI.

And Hibernate documentation says [the same](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/UsingJNDI-boundSessionFactorywithTomcat41):

> It is very useful to bind your SessionFactory to JDNI namespace. In
>   most cases, this is possible to use `hibernate.session_factory_name`
>   property in your configuration. But, with Tomcat you cann't use
>   `hibernate.session_factory_name` property, because Tomcat provide
>   read-only JNDI implementation. To use JNDI-bound `SessionFactory` with
>   Tomcat, you should write custom resource factory class for
>   `SessionFactory` and setup it Tomcat's configuration.

So you need to make custom `SessionFactory` like that:

```
package myutil.hibernate;  

import java.util.Hashtable;  
import java.util.Enumeration;  
import javax.naming.Name;  
import javax.naming.Context;  
import javax.naming.NamingException;  
import javax.naming.Reference;  
import javax.naming.RefAddr;  
import javax.naming.spi.ObjectFactory  
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;  
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;  

public class HibernateSessionFactoryTomcatFactory implements ObjectFactory{  
   public Object getObjectInstance(Object obj, Name name, Context cntx, Hashtable env)   
                 throws NamingException{  

      SessionFactory sessionFactory = null;  
      RefAddr addr = null;  

      try{  
         Enumeration addrs = ((Reference)(obj)).getAll();  

         while(addrs.hasMoreElements()){  
            addr = (RefAddr) addrs.nextElement();  
            if("configuration".equals((String)(addr.getType()))){  
               sessionFactory = (new Configuration())  
                    .configure((String)addr.getContent()).buildSessionFactory();  
            }  
         }  
      }catch(Exception ex){  
         throw new javax.naming.NamingException(ex.getMessage());  
      }  

      return sessionFactory;  
   }  
}
```